# How to Edit Video of YouTubePlayerView

Tags: android, android-studio, java-me

I am really new to Android. I want to edit video before display from YouTubePlayerView. I want to apply some shadders and effects before 
playerView.initialize(DeveloperKey.DEVELOPER_KEY, this).
I have no idea what to do nor i found any related material on internet. I have wasted my couple of hours on this task.Please help me in this regard.Thanks

Comment: Do you have some code you can share or...?

Answer (score 1):

Please present new controller 'viewcontroller1' from your existing view controller.
Data needs to be captured from 'viewcontroller1' and used appropriately.

- (void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent animated: (BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0);